Spring JDBC insert in table with $ in column names
I use spring-jdbc without Hibernate and Oracle DB, which contains columns with names like "SOURCE_CHANGE_TIME$".  I don't have the option to rename the columns. The problem occurs when I try to save data to the database.  The following can be seen in the JdbcTemplate logs:
o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate: INSERT INTO "address" ("id", "SOURCE_CHANGE_TIME$", "full_address") VALUES (?, ?, ?)
o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils: Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type unknown

How to solve the problem with 'SQL type unknown'?
My parent entity:
@Data
public class BaseDwhEntity<ID> implements Serializable, Persistable<ID> {

    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private ID id;

    @Column("SOURCE_CHANGE_TIME$")
    private Instant sourceChangeTime;

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return true;
    }

    ... equals & hashCode here
}

And child:
@Data
@Table("address")
public class Address extends BaseDwhEntity<Long> {

    @Column("full_address")
    private String fullAddress;
    
}

I tried to remove $ from the column name and then the values are successfully saved


I don't really understand what the problem is. What you are showing just looks like normal logging of the JdbcTemplate. So how do you know that something is wrong? Do you get some kind of exception? If so please add the stacktrace to your question.

There is no exception. The problem is that for such columns in the org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils#parseSqlStatement parameter names are filled in incorrectly. Because of this, I get null in the SQL query parameters. I added an image with a breakpoint to the question

Ok, that sounds like an issue with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. I'd recommend creating a little demonstration project (with an in memory database if possible) and creating a ticket at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues
